# angular.js: Use ng-hide or ng-show to hide last two elements of JSON data

Tags: json, angularjs

I am using in my HTML:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items" ng-show="!$last">
    <div>{{ item.value }}</div>
</div>
```

..to hide the last element of a mongodb document (aka JSON data). All other elements of the JSON data gets printed out as expected.

Now how can I hide the last two members of my json data, or alternatively hide by key name, e.g. "__v" and "_id" should be hidden from the user.

Comment: Could you share some of the code you are using to display the data in the view?

Comment: ...Nevermind I see you asked a question 1 hour ago asking how to display the data.

Comment: `ng-show="$index < array.length - 2"`

Comment: I added more code to my question. Whoever did it can remove his downvote now. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `ng-show` directive:

```
<div ng-repeat="friend in friends">
  <li ng-repeat="(key, value) in friend" ng-show="key != '_id' && key != '__v'">
    <input type="text" ng-model="friend[key]">
  </li>
</div>
```

[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/DPQ0x6wGYAwlwaI2Vifp?p=preview)

Answer (score 1):

You could write a custom filter to return all the keys of an object but excluding the ones that you don't want, e.g. keys with `_` prefix.

```
app.filter('keys', function () {
  return function (obj) {
    return Object.keys(obj).filter(function (k) {
      return k && k.charAt(0) !== '_' && k !== '$$hashKey';
    });
  };
});
```

and use it in `ng-repeat` like this:

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="friend in friends">
    <input type="text" ng-repeat="key in friend | keys" ng-model="friend[key]"  />
  </li>
</ul>
```

**Example Plunker:** http://plnkr.co/edit/ws5RqR5zN71ZHY7OCxtD?p=preview